# c# How to filter big txt file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a big txt file (22k Lines;length: 1.4mio) and I have to extract each block to be able to scan it for special words. Depending on this I have to modify the "title" of this block. I got a regex to work but it is rly slow on this amount of rows.

https://regex101.com/r/wN6nB7/24

I needed the flags: SingleLine, MultiLine and Global because the blocks are over multiple lines.

Every Block starts with T;N;;;... and ends with an A;N;;...;

If the Block containts in Text "Tyton" then this should be added in A;N;

Before:

`A;N;400.20;40;NATURAL Muffendruckrohre aus duktilem;Gußeisen;1;0;m;2580;5;0;400.20;`

After:

`A;N;400.20;40;NATURAL Muffendruckrohre aus duktilem;Gußeisen Tyton;1;0;m;2580;5;0;400.20;`

What would be a good method to manipulate the blocks by their content? 
I have tried to find a suitable solution for days.

My concept was:
1. Extract each block
2. Edit the A;N;Title
3. Write only the edited A;N; Title based on their ID`s.

Found today that the List has duplicated IDs...
Hope anyone can help me. My brain.. i`m crying..

Edit1: An example of the input and the groups i need to edit was added.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of input and output?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/ - and stop using RegEx on that kind of work

Comment: You say 22k rows. Do you mean 22k lines? What is a `block`? Is each line a block or can blocks be multiple lines?

Comment: Also, you've shown how this block thing ends, but have not given an example of it beginning.

Comment: Yes, sry... it are 22k Lines; length: 1.4mio. The block`s are multiple lines. It begins everytime with the first T;N; and another ID(number) until the A;N; with the same ID ends. Then it starts again with T;N; and another ID until the A;N; with the same new id ends. I posted.

Comment: Step one: make sure you use `RegexOptions.Compiled`. Step two: if you want help here, you need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, and explain precisely what you've done so far to try to solve that problem, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Comment: I dont rly understand what the problem is to understand my example. I posted the link to regex101.com and there is exact what I want. I already got the right regex match for each group. I want to add every match of group 0. I tried now not ReadAllText but ReadAllLines and search each line first until the A;N; part comes. With some if and foreach statements, i was able to bring it to work. Seams that regex dont like this amount of Lines or duno. Already tested it with RegexOptions.Compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly after 4 days I was able to bring it to work.. Cause im not that versed in c# and I am quite a beginner...

What I wanted cause it seams to be still a lot of questions...

```
<--BeginOfFirstBlock
T;N;400.20;;1;;nach DIN EN 545, mit;2;;Steckmuffenverbindung Tyton, innen mit;
T;N;400.20;;3;;Zementmörtelauskleidung, außen;4;;BioZinalium bestehend aus;
T;N;400.20;;5;;Zink-Aluminium-Legierung (ZnAl 85-15);6;;mit Kupfer (Cu) angereichert,;
T;N;400.20;;7;;flächenbezogene Masse von mind. 400;8;;g/m² NOVO.SIT und blaue;
T;N;400.20;;9;;AQUACOAT-Deckbeschichtung, Baulänge 6;10;;m, Gussrohre für Wasser, NATURAL;
T;N;400.20;;11;;Muffendruckrohr Tyton, DN: 80,;12;;Druckklasse : C50, d1: 98, Gewicht;
T;N;400.20;;13;;(kg) pro 1 m: 12,5;;;;;
A;N;400.20;40;NATURAL Muffendruckrohre aus duktilem;Gußeisen Tyton DN 80;1;0;m;2580;5;0;400.20; <-- ThisHasToBeEditedBasedOnBlock1NeededWordMatches
<-- EndOfFirstBlock
<-- StartOfSecondBlock
T;N;405.20;;1;;nach DIN EN 545, mit;2;;Steckmuffenverbindung Tyton, innen mit;
T;N;405.20;;3;;Zementmörtelauskleidung, außen;4;;BioZinalium bestehend aus;
T;N;405.20;;5;;Zink-Aluminium-Legierung (ZnAl 85-15);6;;mit Kupfer (Cu) angereichert,;
T;N;405.20;;7;;flächenbezogene Masse von mind. 400;8;;g/m² und blaue;
T;N;405.20;;9;;AQUACOAT-Deckbeschichtung, Baulänge 6;10;;m, Gussrohre für Wasser, NATURAL;
T;N;405.20;;11;;Muffendruckrohr Tyton, DN: 100,;12;;Druckklasse : C50, d1: 118, Gewicht;
T;N;405.20;;13;;(kg) pro 1 m: 15,2;;;;;
A;N;405.20;40;NATURAL Muffendruckrohre aus duktilem;Gußeisen Tyton DN 100;1;0;m;2470;5;0;405.20; <-- ThisHasToBeEditedBasedOnBlock2NeededWordMatches
<-- EndOfSecondBlock
AndSoOn...
```

Now.. I tryed to save every block into an string[], into List, Dictionary.. and so on.. I tried even to dont save it but edit it instantly in RAM but was not working...
Now I tried it with `File.ReadAllLines` and with some if and foreach. This seams to work so far and it needs now only 300ms. Still can not understand why it did not work. It was running in debug Mode forever.
Anyway.. my noob way now looks like that:

```
string[] ipt2 = File.ReadAllLines(input, Encoding.Default);
    HashSet<string> matches = new HashSet<string>();
    List<string> dnMatches = new List<string>();

    string[] patHighMatch = new string[] { @"Tyton(?!.*\bSIT\b)(?!.*\bPLUS\b)", @"\bNOVO.SIT\b" };

    for (int i = 0; i < ipt2.Length; i++) // Geht Zeile für Zeile durch
    {
        if (ipt2[i].StartsWith("T;N;")) // Überprüft die Zeile nur wenn die Zeile mit T;N; anfängt
            foreach (var match in patHighMatch) // Geht alle pattern`s im StringArray durch
            {
                Match Match = Regex.Match(ipt2[i], match, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (Match.Success)
                    matches.Add(Match.Groups[0].ToString());
            }

        if (matches.Count != 1 && ipt2[i].StartsWith("T;N;"))
        {
            string[] patLowMatch = new string[] { @"\bTyton.SIT.PLUS\b", @"\bTIS.K\b", @"\bSteckmuffenverbindung[^-]\bSTANDARD\b[^-]", @"[^-]\bSTANDARD\bVI\b[^-]" };
            foreach (var match in patLowMatch)
            {
                Match Match = Regex.Match(ipt2[i], match, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (Match.Success)
                    matches.Add(match);
            }
        }
        if (matches.Count > 0 && ipt2[i].StartsWith("A;N;"))
        {
            ipt2[i] = ipt2[i].Replace("Tyton",String.Join(" ",matches)); // ReplaceTest
            // ipt2[i] = ipt2[i].Replace("Tag", "DONEEE!");
            // Console.WriteLine(ipt2[i].ToString());
            matches.Clear();
            replaces++;
        }
    }
```

Now I have only 2 last questions about RegEx but this is not the right place.. Anyway I have to try my program in the real working environment. Ty anyway for the try.